# Javascript cannot get alert to display

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the below code open an alert box with the text "foo"?

```
function wrapInObject(value) {
    return
    {
        value: value
    };
}
alert(wrapInObject("foo").value);
```

Also why doesn't the below code open an alert box with the text "foobar"?

```
var a = "foo",
    b = a;
b += "bar";
alert(a);
```

Comment: For your `alert()` question... (as the `return` is already solved) you're passing `a` var to the alert function and `a` is only `foo`, it's `b` that's become `foobar` after your var modification.

Answer (score 4):

```
function wrapInObject(value) {
    return {
```

The curly brace should be in same line as return statement. It's because of automatic semi colon insertion by javascript. It assumes that return statement has ended and inserts a semicolon. So it will return undefined. And you're trying to get `value` property of `undefined` which will throw an error. That's why the alert didn't come.

So your code should be:

```
function wrapInObject(value) {
    return {
        value: value
    };
}
```

Regarding second question:

```
var a = "foo",
    b = a;
b += "bar";
alert(a);
```

It's pass by value and not by reference. So changing `b` doesn't change `a` that's why you're getting only `foo`.

If you `alert(b)`, it will give you `foobar`

Comment: @testndtv Was the above answer helpful to you?